# controlling which data to sort in d3.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

Each object in my JSON array has two properties: name & age.  I would like to sort my data in ascending order based on age.  However, I don't know how to tell my code to sort my data based on age only.  Below is the code I have been using.  When I currently run the code, it seems to use the name property, which comes first.

```
var sortSquares = function() {
         svg.selectAll("rect")
            .sort(function(a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a, b)
            })
            .transition()
            .....
            .....
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from your example, but would `d3.ascending(a.age, b.age)` do the trick or am I missing something?

Comment: that did it, and it was so simple! thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer below for completeness (so it's clear your question was answered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort by the attributes of your data, you need to tell `d3.ascending` specifically which attributes to look for. Try this:

```
.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.age, b.age)
})
```